# google visualization errors while resize screen

Tags: html, css, charts, google-visualization

Google chart create an error css `google-visualization-errors-8` in my chart when I resize the browser.

[image]

What is the cause of this error?

**Note** : I am re drawing the graph when the screen is resized.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    drawChart();
});
```

Comment: using a debounced resizer may help, or if the chart appears correctly, except for the error, listen for the error event and simply remove it...

Comment: @WhiteHat I fixed that by removing the error when ever it occurs. using event listener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by removing the error using

```
    var chartC = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('monthlySalesChart'));
    var monthlySalesData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable($scope.dataForMonth);
    chartC.draw(monthlySalesData, dounutOptions);

    // listening the error and removing

    new google.visualization.events.addListener(chartC, 'error', function (googleError) {
         google.visualization.errors.removeError(googleError.id);
    });
```

This might help someone :)